# CryptographicException: Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, cryptography, rsa

In continuing of [Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954416/error-occurred-while-decoding-oaep-padding)

Although I've read all previous asks/posts here I couldn't find a solution.

I'm saving the cryptographed key in a file. Later I'm decrypting it by a Windows Service. Both processes are running under the same machine and calling the same assembly (core) to encrypt and decrypt

I'm stucked since I can't understand why it's throwing an exception.

my code

```
class CryptographyKeyProvider : ICryptographyKeyProvider, ICryptographySaver
    {        
        private readonly ICryptographyFilesProvider _provider;

        public CryptographyKeyProvider(ICryptographyFilesProvider provider)
        {
            _provider = provider;
        }

        #region Util

        private static readonly CryptoKeyAccessRule Rule =
            new CryptoKeyAccessRule(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToLower().Split('\\').Last(),
                                    CryptoKeyRights.FullControl,
                                    AccessControlType.Allow);

        private static CspParameters CspProvider(string keyContainerName, CspProviderFlags flags = CspProviderFlags.NoFlags)
        {
            var cp = new CspParameters
                {
                    KeyContainerName = keyContainerName,
                    Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt | CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore | flags,
                    CryptoKeySecurity = new CryptoKeySecurity()
                };
            cp.CryptoKeySecurity.SetAccessRule(Rule);

            return cp;
        }

        private static void SaveFile(string keyFile, string encryptedPw)
        {
            try
            {                
                File.WriteAllText(keyFile, encryptedPw);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                throw new Exception("Error saving file. " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static string Encrypt(string text, CspParameters cp)
        {            
            string encryptedPw;

            try
            {
                using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp))                
                    encryptedPw = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text), true));                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                throw new Exception("Errror encrypting data. " + ex.Message);
            }

            return encryptedPw;
        }

        private static void ClearContainer(CspParameters cp)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp) { PersistKeyInCsp = false })
                    rsa.Clear();
            }
            catch (CryptographicException ex)
            { }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                throw new Exception("Error cleaning encrypt key. " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static byte[] Decrypt(string containerName, string encriptedData)
        {
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa;

            try
            {
                var cp = CspProvider(containerName, CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey);
                rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                throw new Exception("Error accessing container. " + ex.Message);
            }

            return rsa.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encriptedData), true);
        }

        #endregion

        public byte[] Key1
        {
            get
            {
                var encriptedData = File.ReadAllText(_provider.Key1File);                
                return Decrypt(_provider.Key1ContainerName, encriptedData);
            }
        }

        public void SaveKeyOwner(string text)
        {
            if (File.Exists(_provider.Key1File))
            {                
                throw new Exception("File already exists");
            }            

            var cp = CspProvider(_provider.Key1ContainerName);
            ClearContainer(cp);            
            SaveFile(_provider.Key1File, Encrypt(text, cp));                
        }       
    }
```

Exception

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.
```